# Using select clause in where clause

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I have a record set of just over 8000 records. I have a select clause (within the where clause) which will bring back maybe 10 records.

How many calculations are taking place?

Is it the equivalent of searching through 80,000 (10 x 8000) records? Or is it 64,000,000 (8000 x 8000) because each time it runs through it is searching the whole table again to get the sub set?

The SQL code is below. The purpose of the code is to find jobs that have been closed in the past 7 days and return all related codes whether they are open or not.

Example. If job S15195 closed yesterday, then it should also return X15195, SW15195, W15195C01.

The code works but takes about 30 minutes to run. However as this will be run overnight and emailed then it shouldn't be a problem.

```
SELECT 
JOBHEADER.ORDERNUMBER, 
JOBHEADER.ORDERSTATUS, 
JOBHEADER.ORDERDESCRIPTION, 
JOBHEADER.ORDERDATE, 
JOBHEADER.CUSTOMER, 
JOBHEADER.JOBACTUALCOSTS, 
JOBHEADER.JOBCLOSEDATE, 
JOBHEADER.INVOICEDNETTAMOUNT, 
JOBHEADER.SALESPERSON, 
JOBHEADER.ADDITIONALFIELD_15 AS "PROJECT MANAGER",
Case substring(ORDERNUMBER FROM 2 FOR 1)
  when '1' then substring(ORDERNUMBER FROM 2 for 5)
  when '2' then substring(ORDERNUMBER FROM 2 for 5)
  else substring(ORDERNUMBER from 3 for 5)
End As "PROJECT NUMBER"

FROM JOBHEADER 

WHERE 
Case substring(ORDERNUMBER FROM 2 FOR 1)
  when '1' then substring(ORDERNUMBER FROM 2 for 5)
  when '2' then substring(ORDERNUMBER FROM 2 for 5)
  else substring(ORDERNUMBER from 3 for 5)
End 
IN 
(SELECT 
Case substring(ORDERNUMBER FROM 2 FOR 1)
  when '1' then substring(ORDERNUMBER FROM 2 for 5)
  when '2' then substring(ORDERNUMBER FROM 2 for 5)
  else substring(ORDERNUMBER from 3 for 5)
End As "PROJECT NUMBER"
FROM JOBHEADER 
WHERE DateDiff(Day, JOBHEADER.JOBCLOSEDATE, Cast('NOW' as Date)) <7 
)


ORDER BY JOBHEADER.CUSTOMER
```

Is a select clause within a select clause quicker or is it the same amount of record searches?

Comment: Change the use of `in` to an `exists`. And you should really consider changing your data model. Encoding information into things like order numbers is a bad idea, especially if that information is not available in an easy to query (and easy to index) manner.

Comment: BTW: I don't understand your question, what do you mean with _"Is a select clause within a select clause quicker"_?

Comment: I think my select clause inside a select clause isn't possible, the question is redundant. Sorry for any confusion.